# How can I iterate on Excel sheet rows and put rows into a data structure using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, office365

I am very new in **Excel** and **VBA** and I have the following problem.

I am working on a macro defined into an Excel sheet like this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R29ofaOfSlzqkcjFsAmWvry-knfv8zOn/view

As you can see into this sheet there is a section called **OUT MOVEMENT** that is composed by some rows starting from the **H** column to the **L** column.

I implemented this macro that iterate and show the values into the **K** column starting from the **K3** cell going down untill the last cell with a value.

```
Sub ActualValue()
    Dim outQuantityRange As Range
    Set outQuantityRange = Range("K3", Range("K3").End(xlDown))

    For Each currentOutQuantity In outQuantityRange.Cells
    MsgBox (currentOutQuantity)
    Next
End Sub
```

It works fine but I am asking if using VBA it is possible do something more complex like the following behavior:

Put into a data structure the content of all rows starting from the **H** column to the **L** column (all the rows of the entire **OUT MOVEMENT* section of my Excel sheet).

So this data structure (that can be a list or something like an hashmap that take the **data** field (the **H** column) as key) have to contain some "objects", the first one will contain something like this:

```
(16/12/2017, -198,96 €, ETH, -0,3353050000, null)
```

and the second one something like this:

```
(21/12/2017, -93,98 €, ETH, -0,1400000000, null)
```

Is it possible do something like this into a VBA Excel macro?

Comment: In VBA, you can use Classes as *User Defined Objects* and then collect these objects into a `Dictionary` or `Collection` object.  Is that what you are thinking about?  If so, take a look at Chip Pearson's [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Comment: Depending on what you're aiming for to do with that data later on, I may suggest [Arrays](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html) as well

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is something like this:

```
Sub Concatenate_Data()
    Dim LastRow as Integer, X as Integer, Y as Integer
    LastRow = Range("K3").end(xldown).Row

    Dim Data() As String
    ReDim Data(1 to (LastRow - 2)) As String

    For X = 3 to LastRow
        Data(X - 2) = "(" & Range("H" & X).Value
        For Y = 9 to 12
            If Cells(X, Y) <> "" Then
                    Data(X - 2) = Data(X - 2) & ", " & Cells(X, Y)
                Else
                    Data(X - 2) = Data(X - 2) & ", null"
            End If
        Next Y
        Data(X - 2) = Data(X - 2) & ")"
        MsgBox Data(X - 2)
    Next X
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define record structures and make arrays of them. E.g. put this in your code outside of subs:

```
Type tst
   dat as Date
   cur as Currency
   s1 As String
   dbl As Double
   s2 As String
End Type
```

Then use it in a sub this way:

```
Dim buffer() As tst
 <...>
ReDim buffer(1 To 100)
 <...>
buffer(1).dat = Cells(3, "H")
buffer(1).cur = Cells(3, "I")
etc.
```

Please note that in this solution you need to handle data types because the macro will error if Cells(3, "H") is not of a date type. If it can happen, use CDate function (and CCur, CDbl, etc., see here: [Conversional functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/type-conversion-functions)) or check the content at your convenience. 
If you do not care the content of the cells then it may be more convenient to leverage the Variant types, but then you need not use `Type` definition, you can simply use 2 dim arrays like `Dim buffer (1 to 100, 1 to 5) as Variant`, e.g.:

```
    ReDim buffer(1 To 72,1 To 5)
    <...>
    buffer(1,1) = Cells(3, "H")
    buffer(1,2) = Cells(3, "I")
    etc.
```